# Laptop sleeps by itself - in logs "Sleep requested" - requested by what?

Tags: fedora, systemd, kde, laptop, hibernate

I left my Linux laptop on with the lid open while it was on battery power for several minutes, and it went to "sleep" (according to the systemd journal) - I assume this means the same as hibernation?

But my laptop, for whatever reason, is unable to resume from sleep/hibernate, so it just booted up from scratch and I would have lost whatever unsaved work I had (fortunately, I didn't have any unsaved work).

I went into KDE system settings to try to configure this, but the only  time that it is configured (in KDE) to hibernate is when the battery charge level is "critical", which in turn is configured to mean 5% or below. But the battery level was nowhere near as low as 5%.

If I run

```
journalctl -x --since="2016-06-19 08:00:00" --until="2016-06-19 08:15:00"
```

to see what was happening around that time, there is not much to see:

```
Jun 19 08:04:26 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=dnf-makecache comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr
Jun 19 08:11:04 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1113]: <info>  sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Jun 19 08:11:04 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1113]: <info>  sleeping...
Jun 19 08:11:04 localhost.localdomain audit: NETFILTER_CFG table=nat family=10 entries=52
Jun 19 08:11:04 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1113]: <info>  (wlp2s0): device state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [100 10 37]
Jun 19 08:11:04 localhost.localdomain audit: NETFILTER_CFG table=mangle family=10 entries=40
Jun 19 08:11:04 localhost.localdomain audit: NETFILTER_CFG table=filter family=10 entries=83
Jun 19 08:11:04 localhost.localdomain audit: NETFILTER_CFG table=nat family=2 entries=58
Jun 19 08:11:04 localhost.localdomain audit: NETFILTER_CFG table=mangle family=2 entries=40
Jun 19 08:11:04 localhost.localdomain audit: NETFILTER_CFG table=filter family=2 entries=92
Jun 19 08:11:04 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1113]: <info>  (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 2065
Jun 19 08:11:04 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1113]: <info>  (wlp2s0): DHCPv4 state changed bound -> done
Jun 19 08:11:04 localhost.localdomain avahi-daemon[918]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.101 on wlp2s0.
Jun 19 08:11:04 localhost.localdomain avahi-daemon[918]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.101.
Jun 19 08:11:04 localhost.localdomain kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-23
Jun 19 08:11:04 localhost.localdomain avahi-daemon[918]: Interface wlp2s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jun 19 08:11:04 localhost.localdomain kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier: not a ISO3166 code
Jun 19 08:11:04 localhost.localdomain avahi-daemon[918]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::290:4cff:fe0d:f43e on wlp2s0.
Jun 19 08:11:04 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1113]: <info>  NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Jun 19 08:11:05 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1113]: <warn>  Failed to GDBus.Error:fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.NotConnected: This interface is not connected: disconnect.
Jun 19 08:11:05 localhost.localdomain dbus[943]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Jun 19 08:11:05 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
-- Subject: Unit sleep.target has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit sleep.target has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Jun 19 08:11:05 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Sleep.
-- Subject: Unit sleep.target has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit sleep.target has begun starting up.
Jun 19 08:11:05 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
-- Subject: Unit systemd-suspend.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit systemd-suspend.service has begun starting up.
Jun 19 08:11:05 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
-- Subject: Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has begun starting up.
Jun 19 08:11:05 localhost.localdomain systemd-sleep[19112]: Suspending system...
-- Subject: System sleep state suspend entered
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- The system has now entered the suspend sleep state.
```

How can I find out what caused my laptop to go to sleep?

Comment: This is `NetworkManager` sleeping, not system. It will be configured in network configuration.

Comment: Yes but lower in the logs there are more messages related to the system sleeping. I will update the post with more log messages.